# PgDn not working in IE7 after clicking on a question due to some focus issue

Tags: bug, status-declined, keyboard, internet-explorer-7, scrolling

I usually squizz through SO by opening the frontpage, then right-clicking on the questions I find interesting or want to help answering and open them *in a new tab*.

When I open SO in IE7 and do as described above, the page stops responding to PgDn. It works when it first loads, then stops working when a new tab is loaded in the background. If I hit the scrollbar once, it's responsive again. It's been like this for a while.

Even though this is not a major issue, it's still something that someone should look into.

Comment: I can certainly see how you would find this annoying. Unfortunately, the team has indicated that IE7 is now in the same bucket as IE6, development-wise. In other words, they'll only fix bugs that make the site unusable.

Comment: @Popular demand: Add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. Otherwise I'll just use Jeff Atwood's since his is identical (but you were first).

Comment: thanks, but my answer wasn't exactly the same as Jeff's. Just choose his. Besides... he's Jeff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Popular is correct -- IE7 is the new IE6.

In other words

- it is the *absolute minimum* browser required to use the site
- we will only fix bugs in IE7 that make the site unusable
- we do not guarantee the site will look absolutely correct in IE7