# 'Log in with StackExchange' is freezing/crashing Internet Explorer 6 & 7

Tags: support, login

Can anyone else confirm this? On my Windows XP virtual machines (clean installations for testing), I cannot log in to StackExchange sites using my StackExchange OpenID if I am using Internet Explorer 6 or 7. IE 8 works fine. When I expect to see the `...` indicator, before the email and password fields appear, is when IE freezes up.

[image: login button]

> [image: blank box]

Comment: [Try a better browser.](https://www.google.com/chrome/)

Comment: Of course I don't use IE 6/7 as my main browser. I explicitly said "for testing". I was wondering if any one else experienced this or knew the exact reason behind the issue.

Comment: The iframe looks sucky though, in up to and including IE8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/142114), the Stack Exchange network's support for IE 6 and 7 are as follows:

> - IE 6 (and earlier) — unsupported ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/there-is-no-option-for-commenting-in-ie6/70032#70032))
> - IE 7 — minimally supported ([source 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/there-is-no-option-for-commenting-in-ie6/70032#70032), [source 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69990/pgdn-not-working-in-ie7-after-clicking-on-a-question-due-to-some-focus-issue/71036#71036))